# Incollection with apacite: year and publisher are not shown

Tags: bibtex, apa-style

I'm using TeXstudio and MiKTeX 2.9, and cite using natbibapa and apacite. My incollection entries from bibtex are not built correctly: year, booktitle and publisher are missing.

input bibtex:

```
@incollection{aikhenvald2003,
  title={{Evidentiality in Tariana}},
  author={Aikhenvald, Alexandra Y},
  editor={Aikhenvald, Alexandra Y and Dixon, R.M.W.}
  booktitle={Studies in Evidentiality},
  pages={131-164},
  year={2003},
  publisher={John Benjamins Publishing Company}
}

@incollection{plungian2010b,
  author      = {Plungian, Vladimir},
  title       = {Types of verbal evidentiality marking: an overview},
  editor      = {Diewald, G and Smirnova, E},
  booktitle   = {{Linguistic realization of evidentiality in European languages}}
  publisher   = {Walter de Gruyter},
  year        = {2010},
  pages={15-58},
}
```

input .tex:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[top=2cm, bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}
\usepackage{tipa} 
\usepackage{gb4e}
\usepackage[font=small]{caption}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{nomencl}


\begin{document}

Test sentence with \cite{aikhenvald2003} and \cite{plungian2010b}.

\bibliography{Proposal}
\bibliographystyle{apacite}

\end{document}
```

In running text, it gives me this output:

Test sentence with Aikhenvald (n.d.) and Plungian (n.d.).

In the references, I get this:

Aikhenvald, A. Y. (n.d.). Evidentiality in Tariana. In A. Y. Aikhenvald & R. Dixon (Eds.), .

Plungian, V. (n.d.). Types of verbal evidentiality marking: an overview. In G. Diewald &
E. Smirnova (Eds.), Linguistic realization of evidentiality in European languages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your entries from this:

```
@incollection{aikhenvald2003,
...
  editor={Aikhenvald, Alexandra Y and Dixon, R.M.W.}
...
}

@incollection{plungian2010b,
...
  booktitle   = {{Linguistic realization of evidentiality in European languages}}
...
}
```

to this (i.e., add a comma at the end of these fields):

```
@incollection{aikhenvald2003,
...
  editor={Aikhenvald, Alexandra Y and Dixon, R.M.W.},
...
}

@incollection{plungian2010b,
...
  booktitle   = {{Linguistic realization of evidentiality in European languages}},
...
}
```

This fixes the problem on my end.